# Separate products in categories WooCommerce Shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the WooCommerce Shop Page how can you separate products into categories, so that they're displayed with a title and then the respective products below?

Product Category Title 1 here Products belonging to that category

Product Category Title 2 here Products belonging to that category here

And so forth...

I tried this code but it is not working.

```html
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_category category="category name"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just sharing the code example here which you need to replace with the loop in archive-product.php

you need to define custom columns if shortcode columns does not work.

also you need to comment the shop loop.

I have tested it and it worked for me.

```
<div class="col-6">
    
<h1>category 1</h1>

    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="8" columns="2" category="category slug 1"]'); ?>

</div>

<div class="col-6">

    <h1>Category 2</h1>

<?php  echo do_shortcode('[products limit="8" columns="2" category="category slug 2"]'); ?>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can get the products using this short code by category [products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" cat_operator="NOT IN"] in woocoomerce.

But on your case you need some customization in to the template you need to go woocommerce template /wp-content/themes/child-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php contain all shop page code.

you can add your code/shortocde in the archive-product.php template which will display in shop page.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Yes, I am aware of the shortcode you mention but since this is the shop page it needs customization like you said. Is there no PHP workaround that simply splits it into categories? If I edit it like you said in the archive-product.php what would I need to add in there?